# How do You Control Column Name Position When Creating CSV Exportable Object Arrays?

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, powershell-4.0, psobject

**REFERENCE SCRIPTS:**

Script 1:

```
$csvList = @()

$csvList += New-Object PSObject -Property @{name="test1";accountname="testuser1";mail="user1@somewhere.com"}
$csvList += New-Object PSObject -Property @{name="test2";accountname="testuser2";mail="user2@somewhere.com"}
$csvList += New-Object PSObject -Property @{name="test3";accountname="testuser3";mail="user3@somewhere.com"}
$csvList += New-Object PSObject -Property @{name="test4";accountname="testuser4";mail="user4@somewhere.com"}

$csvList | Export-Csv c:\temp\testcsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Script 2 (added in edit to reflect extended usage):

```
$aTest = @()

for($x=0;$x -le 5;$x++)
{
    $aTest += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name="test$($x)"; `
                                              AccountName="testuser$($x)"; `
                                              Mail="user$($x)@somewhere.com"}
}

$aTest | Export-Csv c:\temp\testcsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**QUESTION:**

While that script creates my CSV and includes all the data I need in the correct rows, I cannot figure out how to control column position.  Even though I'm ordering and adding the data by `name,accountname,mail` Powershell orders it by `mail,name,accountname`.  ***How can I control the column order?***

*Note:* If I do a screen dump of the contents of `$csvList` before the export the order has already been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `PSObject` is essentially a hashtable. There is no ordering of values in a hashtable.  `Select-Object` can reformat the order for you.
Make your last line:

```
 $csvList | Select-Object name,accountname,mail | Export-Csv c:\temp\testcsv2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Got the idea from this forum question: [Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6702057c-a221-4c3b-ade0-c79c63498ec2/when-i-use-exportcsv-the-columns-are-not-ordered-in-the-correct-order?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: Worked like a charm, extra kudos for including your source ;)  As soon as the 'mark as answer' timer expires I'll accept your response as the answer.  In hindsight, I don't know why select didn't occur to me.

Comment: Actually, if he had done `[Ordered]@{'Name'='value';'NextName'='OtherValue'}` it would have ordered the hashtable values.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running V4, they added a type accelerator ([PSCustomObject]) for creating PS Objects that uses an ordered hash table so the properties stay in the order they were declared in the hash literal.

```
$(
[PSCustomObject]@{name="test1";accountname="testuser1";mail="user1@somewhere.com"}
[PSCustomObject]@{name="test2";accountname="testuser2";mail="user2@somewhere.com"}
[PSCustomObject]@{name="test3";accountname="testuser3";mail="user3@somewhere.com"}
[PSCustomObject]@{name="test4";accountname="testuser4";mail="user4@somewhere.com"}
) | Export-Csv c:\temp\testcsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Edit: Example using a loop to build up an ordered hash table:

```
foreach ($i in 1..4)
 {
   $ht = [ordered]@{}
   $ht.name = "test$i"
   $ht.accountname = "testuser$i"
   $ht.mail = "user$i@somewhere.com"
   [PSCustomObject] $ht
 }
```

Comment: +1 for a correct answer to my question.  I'd only point out that this option doesn't appear to work well in a script where object data is added by foreach/for loops.

Comment: If your building up a hash table by adding entries in a loop, there is a type accelerator ([ordered]) to start with an ordered hash table - eg $ht=[ordered]@{}. The keys will stay in the order they were added to the hash table, and a PS object created from that hash table will have it's properties in that order.

Comment: I really appreciate your taking the time to append with a loop solution.  I've tried to adapt your suggestion and can't seem to get the data right or I get an error that "a hash table can only be added to another hash table".  I totally get that this is likely user error stemming from a lack of experience on my part, but if you could update your answer with a small example I'd love to learn from it.

Comment: OK.  Added an example (hopefully that's what you were after.  Note: the ordered hash table can also be used with New-Object if you rather use that than the [PSCustomObject] type accelerator.